# Can I read a value from one SharePoint web part into the the form for a list in another web part?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, infopath

I'm not sure if it's possible to do what I'm hoping, but maybe I'll get lucky. It has to do with setting form fields in a SharePoint 2010 list, using InfoPath forms.

Basically, I have one list with requests from several vendors. Each vendors has their own requests page which is a Web Part Page with one web part: a list of submissions with a custom view applied that filters it only to them. This is a (clunky but functional) way to ensure each vendor only sees their own requests. To submit a new request, they click on the "Add Item" link at the bottom of the list web part. At this point, a customized InfoPath form pops up, and they add their request.

In the form, one of the fields is "Vendor". What I would like to achieve is to have the InfoPath form read something on the page which tells it which vendor's page it was called from and pre-select that vendor (I could then disable the control so they couldn't change it). I am happy to alter the calling page as needed, or to configure the InfoPath form (can you custom-configure GET or POST values or anything to define a field that way?).

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Can you use query string value for this task? If yes,check https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2010/06/03/how-to-pass-querystring-data-into-an-infopath-form/

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like my corporate IT overlords have disabled for entire Forms web part section, so that doesn't work. Any other options?